# What happens to information when a while loop unexpectedly breaks?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, terminology

```
i = 0

while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
    time.sleep(5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    i+=1
    time.sleep(5)
```

So let's say while parsing through, let's say, 20 pages, the code unexpectedly breaks after clicking 2 pages. What would the value of i be? 0 or 2?

Answer (score 0):

Even if the loop hits the break statement, it exits smoothly since you're catching the exception. So, all the information including the value of `i` will be safe as expected.

On the other hand, if some other exception occurs which was not caught, the program terminates quickly with non zero exit code and you won't be able to use any such info.